# Spring Controllers registered twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC configuration file I have this sections:

```
    <bean id="handler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"
          p:alwaysUseFullPath="true"
          p:contentNegotiationManager-ref="contentNegotiationManager"
          p:useRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch="true" />
```

and

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tarhun.geo" use-default-filters="false">
     <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The problem is that Controller mappings are registered twice, i.e. in logs I see that each mapping message is duplicated:

> annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:217 - Mapped "{[/rest/company/{companyId}],methods=[],params=[],heade....

I think problem in that custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` definition. Becuase when I removing it - my controllers are mapped only once. But I still need it, becuase if I remove it I'm getting exception when trying to call API: `No mapping found...`

Can you please suggest something?

FYI, I also have other Spring context configuration files, but I'm sure they doesn't load controllers 2nd time (I even used `context:exclude=Controller` to prevent that).

Comment: you don't need it, there's should be default mapping processing.

Comment: @RomanC ok, I'll try to remove it. But still, I'm a bit confused how it can be problem? As I understand all what doing this 1st config section (where we declared `handler` bean) - it  is just configuration `of RequestMappingHandlerMapping` singleton. And later this configured bean should be used internally by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

In your mvc configuration, components are scanned twice and you do not need to do that.

In configuration, you may set annotation driven configuration and your xml configuration should like below.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<mvc:annotation-driven> 
    <mvc:message-converters>
         <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/> 
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tarhun.geo" />

<!-- UI resources exclusions from servlet mapping -->
<mvc:resources location="/ui/" mapping="/ui/**"/>
```

Adding include/exclude filters are optional if you only want to load Controller, Service or Repository

Comment: Why they are scanned twice? Because of  `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`?

Comment: Yes. 
Please read [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) documentation. It anyways scans the Controller and RequestMapping and generates RequestMappingInfo object. You do not need to do this if you configuration annotation-driven scan in xml.